# SignalR pass IProgress<T> from js client to hub

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr, signalr-hub

Is it possible to pass `IProgress<T>` from js client to the C# SignalR hub? What I'm trying to do is:

On the hub side:

```
public class ProgressHub : Hub<IProgressHub>
{
    public async Task Foo(string jobId, IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Started monitoring {jobId}");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // Simulate some work
            progress.Report(i);            
        }        
    }
}

public interface IProgressHub
{
    Task Foo(string jobId, Progress<int> progress);
}
```

On the js side:

```
connection
    .invoke("Foo", "this-is-job-id", progressPercentage => console.log(`Processed ${value}%`))
    .then(() => console.log("Processing done"));
```

The method on signalr hub gets called, but IProgress always ends up being null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out answer in [Differences between ASP.NET SignalR and ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences)

> The ability to pass arbitrary state between clients and the hub (often called HubState) has been removed, **as well as support for progress messages**. There is no counterpart of hub proxies at the moment.

Finally I've decided to do the following:

On the hub side: `RegisterToProgress([...])` which will internally call `SendProgress([...])` that will send messages to client.

On the js client side: call `RegisterToProgress` and listen to `SendProgress` messages.